Predicate Logic: Is there a particular reason for using proof of contradiction here?
In Logic in Computer Science, the solution to 2.3.9 (d) is as follows :
https://i.sstatic.net/TMR5LzRJ.png
Can this question be proved without using contradiction, as shown below?
\begin{array}{}
1 \quad \forall x P(x) \to S \quad \text{prem} \\
------------\\
2 \quad x_0 \quad P(x_0)\to S \quad \forall x e\ 1 \\
3 \quad \exists x (P(x) \to S) \quad \exists x\text{i } 2 \\
------------\\
4 \quad \exists x (P(x) \to S) \quad \exists x\text{e } 1, 2-3 \\
\end{array}

This can't be proven without some classical principle, as it is not valid intuitionistically (in fact it's not valid classically either if you don't assume that something exists ($\exists x. \top$).

Your step 2 is wrong: you cannot apply Universal Instantiation (aka: $(\forall \text E)$) to the formula $\forall x P(x) \to S$ because the universal quantifier applies only to $P(x)$.
Intuition: assume that $P(x)$ does hold for some objcet in the domain but not for every one and that $S$ is false. We have that the premise is true, because $\text F \to \text F$ is True.
But if we choose an $x_0$ whatever, we may pick an object of the domain such that $P(x_0)$ holds: in this case the conclusion is $\text T \to \text F$, which is False.
See also this post.

Thank you, so the proof by contracdiction seems the only way?

About the intuition, how can you pick an object that $P(x_0)$ holds from the domain that $P(x)$ does not hold for every object?

@RuntimeErrorz - clarified... $\lnot \forall xPx$ is not the same with $\forall x \lnot Px$.

Thanks. But it seems that $P(x)$ does hold for some object in the domain but not for every one and that $S$ is false doesn't satisfy $\forall x P(x) \to S$. The objects that hold may lead to $T \to F$?

@RuntimeErrorz - let $P(x)$ be "x is Even" and consider natural number. It is clear that "Every natural is Even" is false, but this does not mean that "every natural is not even (i.e. Odd)" is true. Thus if $\forall x Px \to S$ is "IF every number is Even, Then $(1 \ne 0)$" we have the case $\text F \to \text F$. But we can pick as $x_0$ the number $2$ and now we have "IF 2 is Even, THEN $(1 \ne 0)$" which is $\text T \to \text F$.

Really appreicate your time and patience, even for my first question.

It depends on the rules you have available to you. For example, here is a proof that doesn’t use a proof by contradiction but instead relies on a number of equivalence principles. Some proof systems may include those principles as part of their rules, but other systems do not.
$1. \forall x \ P(x) \to S$
$2. \neg \forall x \ P(x) \lor S$ (Implication 1)
$3. \exists x \ \neg P(x) \lor S$ (Quantifier Negation 2)
$4. \exists x \ \neg P(x) \lor \exists x \ S$ (Null Quantification 3)
$5. \exists x (\neg P(x) \lor S)$ (Distribution $\exists$ over $\lor$ 4)
$6. \exists x (P(x) \to S)$ (Implication 5)

Note that the equivalence $A \to B \equiv \neg A \lor B$ is classical, and the "null quantification" rule assumes a nonempty domain.

@NaïmFavier True. And it is clear from the picture of the posted proof that that is exactly what this textbook assumes.
